# Administrator vs Normal User in Ejabberd

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

How to differentiate between administrator and normal user in my ejabberd server?
To register an admin, I use the following command: 
**ejabberdctl register username servername password**
How to register normal user into ejabberd?

Also, I want to send custom tags in XMPP message because it's a chat system based on different types of events (number of events: 3). So, I want to add an extra xml tag named as .

Thanks

Comment: the user registration command is the same, are you asking how differently you give admin rights to a given user?

Comment: Yes, I don't want anyone to change anything except admin

Comment: then register any user with that command and change rights trough acl https://www.ejabberd.im/files/doc/guide.html#htoc15

Comment: Okay. That means if I put {acl, admin, {user, "aleksey","example.com"}} in config file, then the user registered with JID: aleksey@example.com will be the administrator and rest registered users will be the normal users??